# Using Regular Expressions to get Data Between Two Newlines in Expect

Tags: linux, expect

I'm writing this expect script that ssh into a device and runs a cat command to view the mac address of the device. I wan't to assign this mac address to a variable. However, I'm having trouble parsing the data.

This is the contents of my `expect_out(buffer)`:

```
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address\r\nd0:21:f9:4f:c1:68\r\nU6-Lite-BZ.6.0.21# "
```

The `d0:21:f9:4f:c1:68` is what I actually want.

This is what commands I have been running:

```
expect -re {(?n)^d0.*}
set test "$expect_out(0,string)"
puts "$test"
```

And this does store the correct output to a variable. However, normally I wouldn't know the first 2 chars of the mac address (`d0`), so I need to edit the line such that it just reads after the newline to the next newline. Or reads a number of characters after the first newline ending. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know the file content is a MAC addr which is 17 chars <sup>(`:` and HEX digits)</sup> long --

```
expect -re {[:[:xdigit:]]{17}}
set test "$expect_out(0,string)"
puts "$test"
```

Comment: This works thanks! I mentioned earlier that I would ssh into a device initially, if I exit the ssh connection would the variable still hold/retain its value?

Comment: After the Expect script exits, all vars in it will also be gone. You can save the script's output in a shell var (e.g. `mac=$(expect /the/ssh.exp)`) or a tmp file (e.g. `expect /the/ssh.exp > /tmp/somefile`).

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells What do you mean by scripts output? What is held in the expect_out(buffer)? How can I return multiple variables if I need?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
set lines [split $expect_out(buffer) \n]
set macaddr [string trim [lindex $lines end-1] \r]
```

Comment: If you place `puts $macaddr` after these lines is it supposed to output the mac address? Since when I tried it output nothing.